# Run alembic upgrade migrations in a transaction

Tags: transactions, database-migration, alembic

Does `alembic upgrade head` run inside a transaction so that all database alterations succeed, or fail? If not, why was it designed this way?

Answer (score 19):

My understanding is alembic runs inside a transaction for databases that support it, like Postgres. If you're on a database that does not support this (*cough* MySQL *cough*), you can't use this functionality.

Comment: Why it won't run in transaction in MySQL

Comment: MySQL DDL commands like `ALTER/CREATE/DROP TABLE` automatically commit any in-progress transactions, so it's usually "safer" (at least, more predictable) to not use transactions at all. In other words, schema alterations aren't contained in transactions.

Comment: What about SQLite? It [supports transactions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) but I've seen migrations "partially" execute, (up to the point of not updating the revision in the db).

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I had a `CREATE TABLE` that persisted through a failed migration. I think this is because [*"if you are within a transaction and issue a command like CREATE TABLE ..., VACUUM, PRAGMA, the sqlite3 module will commit implicitly before executing that command. There are two reasons for doing that. The first is that some of these commands don’t work within transactions."*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).

Answer (score 6):

That's something you can decide within the `env.py`, which is where you customize the behaviour of the migrations to suit your setup. You can see how to make sure your upgrades happen in a transaction from the template provided as an example for generic databases: https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/eaaafbca88f85f5432e04affe1f94cbf1ad06080/alembic/templates/generic/env.py#L64

```py
def run_migrations_online():
    # ...
    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()
```