# How to rollback all migrations if error occurs?

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

It seems there is a way to [rollback](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/offline.html?highlight=rollback) all changes on error but the example script seems odd because the reference `session`, used in the script, is never defined or imported:

```py
from alembic import context
import myapp
import sys

db_1 = myapp.db_1
db_2 = myapp.db_2

def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations *without* a SQL connection."""

    for name, engine, file_ in [
        ("db1", db_1, "db1.sql"),
        ("db2", db_2, "db2.sql"),
    ]:
        context.configure(
                    url=engine.url,
                    transactional_ddl=False,
                    output_buffer=open(file_, 'w'))
        context.execute("-- running migrations for '%s'" % name)
        context.run_migrations(name=name)
        sys.stderr.write("Wrote file '%s'" % file_)

def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations *with* a SQL connection."""

    for name, engine in [
        ("db1", db_1),
        ("db2", db_2),
    ]:
        connection = engine.connect()
        context.configure(connection=connection)
        try:
            context.run_migrations(name=name)
            session.commit()    # <---
        except:
            session.rollback()  # <---
            raise

if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

It's **very** weird (imho) that this is no default behavior but I want to rollback *every* change from a migration script in case an error occurs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095039/run-alembic-upgrade-migrations-in-a-transaction

Comment: Afaic it is the default behaviour, if the DBMS in use supports transactional DDL.